# Run Play framework project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, run-configuration

What file should I run in order to open and see how my Play project works?

Here is a screen shot of my project opened in Intellij Idea:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look.

[image: screenshot]

For more information you should read - [Getting Started with Play 2.x](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

> A play application has several entry points, one for each URL. We call
>   these methods 'action' methods. Action methods are defined in special
>   classes that we call 'controllers'

For running Play Framework applications with Intellij Idea tools you need to download and install `Scala` plugin.

Then `press the down arrow in you right top corner -> Edit Configurations -> + -> Play 2 App -> select play module`

[image]

You can run you play-app via command line executing `play run` under the application root directory.

Userful resources:

[Configuring Intellij Idea for runnin Play-application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html)

[Quick quide to starting up the Play project](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.1/guide1)